# Android ListView Faded Edge

Tags: android, listview

By default, the faded edge at the top of a ListView only shows up once you start scrolling through the list.  Is there any way to have that top faded edge shading show up even when you haven't scrolled down at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would remove the fading edge from the list view and just add an ImageView right above your ListView(perhaps both of them together in a layout) and make the src the drawable of the fading edge.

You can find the drawables in your sdk folder/platforms/platform-version/data/res/